# Why aren't there quotes in sys.argv when they were used at the command line?

Tags: python, shell, command-line-arguments

Is this a bug?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
# filename: tmp.py
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

Invoked:

```
python tmp.py find . -name '*.py'
```

Actual output:

```
['tmp.py', 'find', '.', '-name', '*.py']
```

Expected output:

```
['tmp.py', 'find', '.', '-name', "'*.py'"]
```

Note the lack of quotations within the actual output.

Comment: Why do you expect literal quotes?

Comment: Why shouldn't I?  I'm not asking python to do anything but extract what's _actually_ on the command-line.

Comment: ...that is to say, if you call `subprocess.Popen(['foo', 'hello'])`, you don't (well, shouldn't) expect `foo` to see the Python quotes around the literal argument `hello`. In the same way, you can't expect other programs to see quotes that are purely shell syntax and not passed to the software being executed.

Comment: @BrianBruggeman It has extracted exactly what you put on the command line ... your misunderstanding is around how `bash` works and what literal quotes mean to `bash` ... also worth trying `python tmp.py 'find' '-name' '*.py'`

Comment: ...so, when you talk about a "command line" -- that's a shell construct. The *actual* calling convention when one UNIX program starts another is an array of C strings.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I completely am find with your Popen example.  My question is really around how python is reading in the command-line arguments.

Comment: Where is the `'.'` supposed to come from?

Comment: As an array of C strings, which is what they *actually are*. It has no way of knowing what they were before they were transformed into that by the shell.

Comment: @user2357112 probably typo, since `find` needs a start dir.

Comment: Take a quick look at `man 2 execve` -- that's what a program actually calls at the OS level to start another program. You'll see there's nowhere you can put a command line in that, so *the command line isn't available to the program being started*. Thus, Python has no possible way it could tell how the shell command that started it was originally quoted.

Comment: The point of my Python example is that it's the same thing happening in shell -- the quotes are *syntax*, not data; and being as they're syntax, they aren't part of what's passed to the program being started.

Comment: I'm sad someone downvoted this question.  Thanks for the explanation and the question title edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell is responsible for breaking down the command it's running into a list of C strings. *Those strings* are then passed to the program being run.

In the example:

```
python tmp.py find . -name '*.py'
```

...the argument list a correctly-implemented shell will generate for the `argv` element of [the `execve` syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) would look (in C syntax) like:

```c
char[][]{ "python", "tmp.py", "find", ".", "-name", "*.py", NULL }
```

---

When Python runs, it doesn't know what the original command was: It has no way of knowing if you typed `'*.py'` or `\*.py` or any other thing; it only sees the argument list the shell handed off to the operating system.

Answer (score 6):

no, because your shell removes the quotes before passing the argument to python (else it would *expand* the `*.py` wildcard)

To get what you want you'd need:

```
python tmp.py find -name "'*.py'"
```

Note that this behaviour is shell dependent. On windows, since single quotes have no particular meaning, passing `'*.py'`, you would get:

```
['tmp.py', 'find', '.', '-name', "'*.py'"]
```

Also note that quote-protected wildcards have no real interest on the python side, since you'd need to strip the quotes to be able to evaluate them with `glob.glob`